# Unfold vCard lines in shell

Tags: shell, text

vCard lines can be folded by inserting "\r\n " (that's a space at the start of the new line), but I'm struggling to unfold them with the line-oriented GNU tools (sed, cut). Any ideas? Effectively, from the string

```
foo
 bar
baz
ban
 bay
 bal
```

it must return

```
foobar
baz
banbaybal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [solution](http://ilfilosofo.com/blog/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/): `sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\r\n //g;p}'` (DOS newline mode).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{s=s" "$0}END{gsub("  +","",s);gsub(" ","\n",s);print s}' file

foobar
baz
banbaybal
```

Comment: How do I get rid of the empty line at the beginning? I have to distinguish it from other empty lines in the input.